# postgresql session variables gets reset when a not condition is used

Tags: postgresql

I am using the Postgres session variables for handling pagination in my query.

I have a table message (id,uid,body,user_id,posted_date).
I select the messages belonging to a given user and then order by posted_date. Now I have to return the messages after a given uid in the list of the messages. For this I use the session variables,

```
select set_config('paging.count', '0',false)

SELECT * 
FROM 
 (SELECT 
        m2.uid, m2.id,
        case when uid = 'XYZ' THEN
            set_config('paging.count', '1',false)
        WHEN current_setting('paging.count') = '1' THEN
            '1'
        ELSE
            '0' END as offset
    FROM
        (SELECT m1.*,mu.* FROM schema_1.message m1
        WHERE m1.user_id = 1 AND m1.id IN (4078,4076,4080,4031,4055,4056,4057,3596,4193,4467,4389,4285,4338,)
        ORDER BY posted_date) m2  ) m
    WHERE m.offset = '1' and m.uid   <> 'XYZ'
```

Here I initialize the session variable to 1 when the given uid is selected in the query, all the messages after that uid will have offset as 1 and thus I will get all the messages after the given message by adding a condition for offset. But this query works fine only when I don't use the last **NOT** condition. But as soon as I apply the  **NOT** condition my session variables kind of get reset to the value I initialized at the start of the query.
I just can't figure out what wrong am I doing??
According to my knowledge this should work fine.

Comment: This won't work. A `SELECT` statement is not a `for` loop. Postgres can and will rearrange your query as it sees fit. In particular, since `current_setting` is [`STABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-volatility.html), it might only be evaluated once per query. You should try [a different approach](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/3/35/Pagination_Done_the_PostgreSQL_Way.pdf).

Comment: I can't see any NOT in your code?..

Comment: @Nick : This query work perfect when I remove the where condition on the last line of my code and store the result set into a temporary table. The offset values are exactly how I want and I can achieve my goal with temporary table, after this query I execute current_setting then it gives me output as 1 which is correct as I have set it to 1, but when I use this query with the where condition and use a negation'<>' condition, current_setting gives me '0'. So, I think logically the approach shoudl work fine just I cannot understand why it gives problem when i hit the '<>' condition

Comment: @VaoTsun: NOT means any negation condition, here in my query it is '<>'

Comment: sorry, I just used to thing <> is != and NOT is NOT, like NOT NULL, NOT TRUE. Anyway now I see what you meant

Comment: is m2.uid different column from uid (that is equal to 'XYZ')?..

Comment: @VaoTsun : sorry, there was a mistake in the query, the m2.uid is same as uid, updated the query. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `    case when uid = 'XYZ' THEN set_config('paging.count', '1',false)` and then `WHERE m.offset = '1' and m.uid   <> 'XYZ'`... what are you trying to do?.. as if you expect `select 'result' where false` to give you a row

Comment: @VaoTsun : The derived query (m2) gives me a set of messages sorted by posted date. Now I want the messages which are posted after "XYZ". This is just an example the criteria for sorting can change eg : poster name etc. So here what I want to do is that in teh derived query (m), I set the offset to one for those who appear after XYZ, so by querying (m) with condition as offset = '1', I can get those, but my problem is I have to exclude "XYZ", which will alos have offset as '1'. So, I add a '<>' condition for "XYZ". Hope you got my point

Comment: @Ashish: Again, the Postgres planner is free to rearrange and even remove these function calls. You cannot control or predict where or when it will choose to do this. Even if it *seems* to be working, it might be broken by a Postgres upgrade, or an autovacuum run, or even for a specific value of `uid`. There are [better ways](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/3/35/Pagination_Done_the_PostgreSQL_Way.pdf) of handling pagination which are not so fragile.

Comment: @NickBarnes : Thanks, I got your point. I have to think beyond the session variables as it behavior is not as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
select
   'result'
  , case when 'q'='q' THEN
            set_config('paging.count', '1',false)
        WHEN current_setting('paging.count') = '1' THEN
            '1'
        ELSE
            '0' END as offset
) SUBQ
where "offset" = '1' and 'q' <> 'q'
```

will give you no rows and it is expected result

Comment: If you change you condition ('q'='q') to (uid = 'q'), then the row that are returned after SUBQ must have the offset as '1' and then the result should have some rows which are after the 'q'.